# Is this way of doing code in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coding-style

Well, i am new to node js. I want to know about my coding structure. I am asking this question because I am writing lots of return and it looks odd to me some time

```
setTimeout(() => {
     return _db.collection(_encycUsers).findOne(
     // search basis.
      {"_id" : require("mongodb").ObjectId(_userId)}).then(
      // on a successful search.
       (_encycUsersData) => {
         // if return is not empty.
         if(!(_help.isEmpty(_encycUsersData))) {
           return _db.collection(_encycUsers).updateOne(
            // search basis.
            {"_id" : require("mongodb").ObjectId(_encycUsersData["_id"])}, {
             "$unset" : {"_otp" : _otp, "_state" : ["request.otp.sent", "request.otp.delete"]},
             "$set" : {"_state" : "request.otp.reSent"}
            }).then(
               // on successful encyc update.
                () => {
                       _debug(_encycUsersData);
                       // search user after successful otp delete.
                       return _db.collection(_encycUsers).findOne(
                       // search basis.
                        {"_id": require("mongodb").ObjectId(_encycUsersData["_id"])}).then(
                          // on successful user search.
                             (_encycUsersFindData) => {
                             ...
```

Comment: Classic "callback hell". My tips is to read up on how to avoid it, https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-async-best-practices-avoiding-callback-hell-node-js-at-scale/

Comment: thanks for the link. no regret because I am already fed up with this. :)

Comment: thanks for the link. no regret because I am already fed up with this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your return statements seem to be useless.
In

```
setTimeout(function, timeout)
```

The return value of the function is basically ignored.
And in your code, it's not interesting that your function returns.  What is interesting is that the find and update methods you call return promises and you call the `then` method on these promises.

So, removing the return statements and ending up with code like

```
setTimeout(() => {
    function1().then((result) => {
        function2(something_based_on_result).then((result2 => {...})
    })}, 1000)
```

is a common Javascript practice.
There are various approaches to reduce the length of these chains.
If you're using Node greater than 7.6, you can use asynchronous functions and write things like:

```
async function foo(){
    let result = await function_returning_promise() #calls then on the promise under the covers
    let result2 = await function2(data_based_on_result)
}
```

And in a few years that asynchronous pattern will be quite common.  Today, the chained series of then tends to be what people write.

Comment: Remind me which version that became the default with no command line options?

Comment: @J.Doe if my answer answered your question, please accept it

Comment: :(  think positive and the reply was positive too.